# place the button overlapping top-right corner of the ui-modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

```js
<script>
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.extend({}, $.ui.dialog.prototype, {
  _title: function(title) {
    if (!this.options.title) {
      title.html("&#160;");
    } else {
      title.html(this.options.title);
    }
  }
}));
$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  　　height: 300,
  width: 830,
  dialogClass: 'myTitleClass',
  modal: true,

  title: "Carpe Diem. Nunca Acredito Posteiro",
  closeOnEscape: false,
  open: function(event, ui) {
    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', ui.dialog | ui);
  },
  buttons: {
    "Save": function() {
      $(this).trigger(updateKeyword());
    }
  }
})

$("#opener").click(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

```css
input#opener {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s ease;
  top: 80%;
  left: 45%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: rgba(4, 115, 184, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  font-style: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2.5;
  position: center;
  border-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.myTitleClass .ui-dialog-title {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
}

.myTitleClass .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  overflow: visible;
  background: rgba(4, 115, 184, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 60px;
}

.myTitleClass .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: rgba(4, 115, 184, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-style: none;
}

.myTitleClass .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: rgba(4, 115, 184, 1);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-style: none;
}

.ui-widget-overlay {
  position: fixed;
}

.ui-widget-overlay {
  background: none;
}

.myTitleClass .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  border-radius: 17px;
  height: 33px;
  margin: -10px 0 0;
  padding: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -28px;
  top: -24%;
  width: 33px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="button" id="opener" value="Register Keyword" />
</button>
<div id="dialog">Merry Christmas.
</div>
```

I am struggling to place close button overlapping on the top-right corner of ui-modal-dialog. Even if I allowed overflow: visible, the close button still is getting stuck in the corner. How can I do place the close button like the following image? Shoud I hide the close button on ui-modal-dialog and need to use only html and css without jquery.

[image]

```js
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.extend({}, $.ui.dialog.prototype, {
  _title: function(title) {
    if (!this.options.title) {
      title.html("&#160;");
    } else {
      title.html(this.options.title);
    }
  }
}));
$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  　　height: 300,
  width: 830,
  dialogClass: 'myTitleClass',
  modal: true,

  title: "Carpe Diem. Nunca Acredito Posteiro",
  closeOnEscape: false,
  open: function(event, ui) {
    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', ui.dialog | ui);
  },
  buttons: {
    "Save": function() {
      $(this).trigger(updateKeyword());
    }
  }
})

$("#opener").click(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

```css
input#opener {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s ease;
  top: 80%;
  left: 45%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: rgba(4, 115, 184, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  font-style: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2.5;
  position: center;
  border-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.myTitleClass .ui-dialog-title {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
}

.myTitleClass .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  overflow: visible;
  background: rgba(4, 115, 184, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 60px;
}

.myTitleClass .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: rgba(4, 115, 184, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-style: none;
}

.myTitleClass .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: rgba(4, 115, 184, 1);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-style: none;
}

.ui-widget-overlay {
  position: fixed;
}

.ui-widget-overlay {
  background: none;
}

.myTitleClass .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  border-radius: 17px;
  height: 33px;
  margin: -10px 0 0;
  padding: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -28px;
  top: -24%;
  width: 33px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="opener" value="Register Keyword">
</button>
<div id="dialog">Merry Christmas.
</div>
```

Comment: The Fiddle link?

Comment: @Varun https://jsfiddle.net/kimihiro/tf3Lrkdv/?

Comment: Looks like you just need to declare `overflow: visible` on `.ui-dialog`

Comment: please create a valid example snippet your snippet should depict exactly what your problem is whereas currently, it isn't working, are you using bootstrap? which version?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thanks a lot. It worked. Probably I am confused with .ui-dialog-title since I tried it many times.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thanks for your advice! I tried it many times, but it didn't work. So I should have posted the JsFiddle at first. Probably I should delete the answer if nobody answers it.

Comment: looks like you solved your problem, try spend some time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for how to create example snippets

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thanks for your advice. I could not find for the page to make snippet work here. I appreciate it.

Comment: Read this article https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam that's helpful. I will read it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment. I just added

> ```
> .ui-dialog{ overflow: visible;}
> ```

since I was confused with .ui-dialog-title as.ui-dialog. now I was able to fix as the following:

> https://jsfiddle.net/kimihiro/r2aedfmz/show/

1 ".ui-dialog-title-bar",
 2 ".ui-dialog-title",
 3 ".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", 
 4 ".ui-dialog"
[image]